# Determining size of the partition when using Ubuntu Installer

Tags: installation, partitioning, hard-drive

I would like to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside with Windows 7 using the Ubuntu installer, following the [official guide.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-long-term-support) I first chose "Install Ubuntu", then "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7", but in the next step, when I tried to allocate disk space by dragging the divider, I wasn't able to give Ubuntu *less* than 32 GB.

My harddisk has 500 GB, and as the guide states, "Ubuntu needs about 4.5 GB to install, so add a few extra GB to allow for your files." - This surely does not mean *more* than 10-15 GB? Is there a quick and easy way to install Ubuntu on a partition of exactly this size, i.e. without having to choose the "Something else" option at the beginning of the installer procedure?

Maybe someone can explain me why appaerently there is a minimum of 32 GB, given the overall size of my HDD?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are answering your question when you say:

> Is there a quick and easy way to install Ubuntu on a partition of exactly this size,   i.e. without having to choose the "Something else" option at the beginning of the installer procedure?

The quick an easy way is to select the options given to you. The other way is to use the option 'Something else'.

About the 32GB, most users trying ubuntu don't want to have the bare minimal use of hard drive for it, install a few applications and games and find out that they just ran out of space. I think Canonical is trying to give you an useful partition you can actually live with for a while before running out of space.

Finally, there are great guides for installing using the "Something else" and once you do it once you will find it quick, easy and better since you have more control over what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer David, I guess I go for the first option then and will try the automatic Ubuntu installer without manual partitioning. For those with a similar question, a good guide on how to do everything "by hand" can be found at [dedoimedo.com](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/dual-boot-windows-7-ubuntu.html). It was last updated in November 2012.